# How to display number of images from json using listview inside layout adapter and also programmatically to create imageview layouts in android?

Tags: android, json, uiimageview

Here I am using for loop to get the imagelayout inside relative layout it,depends upon the images from server. Sometimes 2 images or 3 images from server.

```
  @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
 static String host = "http://197.0.0.1/";
 static String imgurl=host+"site_media/";

                map=hashmap.get(position);
 InputStream is=null;
                InputStream is1=null;
                Drawable d,d1;
                 String photo1=(map.get(TAG_O));

     int positi=map.get(TAG_O).length();
                //    Log.i("pos",String.valueOf(positi));
                    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.linear);

                    for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
                    {
                   //   Log.i("image",photo1);


                        imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                   //     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluecap_32);
                        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(40,40);
                        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);


               try
                       {     
                    is1 = (InputStream) new URL(imgurl+photo1).getContent();
                       Log.i("photo",photo1);


                       }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    d1 = Drawable.createFromStream(is1, "src name");
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(d1);
                    parentLayout.addView(imageView, i);
                }
                    }
```

Here I am getting many images from particular array list using json. So I want to display the images using imageview layout programmatically with horizontal scrollview and linear layout. But here image are not display in the listview.